# Xelement - get elements

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I'm loading  an xml feed from youtube into xelement like so:

```
  XElement element = XElement.Load(url);
```

This is fine and I get a document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:opensearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/id/uploads</id>
  <updated>2014-01-07T11:43:08.269Z</updated>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
  <title type='text'>Uploads by id</title>
  <logo>http://www.gstatic.com/youtube/img/logo.png</logo>
  <link rel='related' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/stonemarketuk'/>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/333/videos'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/id/uploads'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/id/uploads/batch'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/id/uploads?start-index=1&amp;max-results=25'/>
  <link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/id/uploads?start-index=26&amp;max-results=25'/>
  <author>
    <name>StonemarketUK</name>
    <uri>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/id</uri>
  </author>
  <generator version='2.1' uri='http://gdata.youtube.com'>YouTube data API</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>30</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
      ....entry elements
  </entry>
  <entry>
      ....entry elements
  </entry>
</feed>
```

How do I get the entry elements? I have tried the following:

```
var entries = element.Elements("entry");
var entries = element.Element("feed").Elements("entry");
var entries = element.Nodes().Elements("entry");
```

But none of these return anything

I also debugged and tried `element.Elements().FirstOrDefault()` but this returned null.  `element.Nodes().Count()` returned 41 so should I be trying to get the nodes called entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All elements are in a namespace (`xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'`). You must declare the atom namespace and use it.

It's easy:

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

var xml = XElement.Load(url);
var entry = xml.Elements(atom + "entry");
```

etc.

An easy way to get the right Element name is using `XName.Get()`. If you only have one namespace, you could put it in a seperate function:

```
internal static XName GetXName(string name)
{
    string atomNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    return XName.Get(name, atomNamespace);
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, this is so simple when you know how!  will accept in 3 minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var entryList = element.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "entry");
```

The problem here is that every element without an explicit namespace is implicitly in the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`.  The `LocalName` property can still be used to access the simple name as shown above.  Barring that you need to construct a proper `XName` element which includes this namespace in order to match the 'entry' nodes